# Using postman to access OpenDaylight's REStconf API and configure a YANG Module sitting on a NETCONF Server

Tags: opendaylight, ietf-netconf, ietf-restconf

I am running OpenDaylight Neon with Postman 7.2.0. I have a NETCONF server sitting on a netopeer2 Docker. Since I can get the operational datastore of the server with

```
GET http://192.168.56.2:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/topology/topology-netconf/node/new-netconf-device/yang-ext:mount/
```

I assume that everything is configured correctly.
Still, I have had a hard time trying to edit the config datastore.

Trying to

```
PUT http://192.168.56.2:8181/restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/topology-netconf/node/new-netconf-device/yang-ext:mount/
```

With following payload

```
<bridges xmlns="urn:ieee:std:802.1Q:yang:ieee802-dot1q-bridge">
    <bridge>
        <name>test</name>
    </bridge>
</bridges>
```

Gives me following error:

```
<errors xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-restconf">
    <error>
        <error-type>protocol</error-type>
        <error-tag>malformed-message</error-tag>
        <error-message>Error parsing input: Not correct message root element "bridges", should be "(urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0)data"</error-message>
        <error-info>Not correct message root element "bridges", should be "(urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0)data"</error-info>
    </error>
</errors>
```

1. Am I wrong in only accessing the the mount point with the URL? I want to create a Node with the put command, since there currently is none.
2. I assumed that the part before xmlns is the first root element, which would be the container "bridges" in the ieee802-dot1q-bridge.yang. Is this a misconception?
3. There is no special RESTconf API for the ieee-dot1q-bridge.yang, that's why I try to use the mount point. Is this even possible?